# How do I make my code so that my initial input from text input does not get deleted

Tags: react-native, textinput

my code:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  return (
    
    <SafeAreaView>
    <View style={styles.container}>
    </View>
    <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="John Doe"
        onSubmitEditing={(value) => setName(value.nativeEvent.text)}
      />
      <Text>Welcome: {name}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    borderColor: "gray",
    width: "100%",
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
});
```

when I press enter the value goes to {name}, but when I type in another input and press enter, the initial value gets deleted. I want to keep adding on instead of having the initial value deleted.

Comment: what is it you actually want here? you want to have more than one line of input?

Comment: yes what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to be able to keep adding the name of exercises below by using text input

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the text value into an array instead of a string

```
const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
```

to add to the array like this

```
<TextInput
  style={styles.input}
  placeholder="John Doe"
  onSubmitEditing={(value) => {
    setNames(previousVal => previousVal.concat([value.nativeEvent.text]))
  }}
  />
```

and finally to display

```
{names.map((item,index) => (
    <Text key={index}>Welcome: {item}</Text>
))}
```

Comment: this works fine when I change my text input values before writing another one but I get an error when I do not change the value of my text input and press enter

Comment: the error i get is TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'value.nativeEvent.text')

Comment: try this

onSubmitEditing={(value) => {
 if(value?.nativeEvent?.text){
      setNames(previousVal => previousVal.concat([value.nativeEvent.text]))
 }
}}

what it does is check if the text value is not null

Comment: I get the same error